# Laravel 8: ErrorException::("PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away") when calling DB::unprepared($sql)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I run a laravel seeder:

```
public function run()
    {
        $path = public_path('sql/cities.sql');
        $sql = file_get_contents($path);
        DB::unprepared($sql);    }
}
```

the insert sql file is very big it's stored in public/sql , it's same as this file from github (with insert statements only) : [Cities SQL File](https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/blob/master/sql/cities.sql)

When I run seeder it throw this error:

> D:\codes\laravel\arkanlabs_b2b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:541
> ErrorException::("PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away")

I tried many solutions in stackOverFlow like:
1- maximizing max_allowed_packet to 200M in my.ini (didn't works)
2- maximizing max_execution_time to 300 in php.ini (didn't works)

I also searched and I have a solution not sure if it works or not because I can not determine/apply it which is to max time out connection of mysql

**any help is appreciated !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by setting max_allowed_packet=200MB under **[mysqld]** in **my.ini** then restart your **mysql** .

I was set max_allowed_packet under [mysqldump] which is **wrong**.

---

MySQL dump: is only for exporting sql.
MySQL: is MySQL client (or mysql deamon program) which used to running queries (in my case inserting this big 16 MB sql file)

Reference this serverfault question:  [difference between mysql and mysqldump](https://serverfault.com/questions/233535/difference-between-mysql-and-mysqldump)